# What should I do if my cat vomits his food?

Tags: first-aid, cats

Recently, my 1 year-old cat vomited over my kitchen floor while playing. I was worried and unsure what to do, so I just cleaned him up and made sure he was OK.

What should I do if he vomits again?

Should I take him to a pet hospital?

Why is he even vomiting?

We change his brand of food often; is that related?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, **he was actively playing before vomiting**. It could be that he ate all of his food, then jumped around too much which made him sick.

You should keep an eye on it though. If he vomits again then it's probably worth a trip to the vets just to make sure everything is okay.

Common possible causes for vomiting:

- **Being active after eating** - This can be a common cause, if your cat has just eaten a large amount of food and then proceeds to play/be active, then this could also cause vomiting.
- **Eating grass/other items** - Now grass is probably the most familiar to both dog and cat owners, but your cat could of eaten something that didn't agree with him on his travels. Obvious signs of this are things other than his food inside his vomit, always check for that.
- **Change of food** - Recent changes to a cat's food can also be a factor that causes vomiting, down to it not *agreeing* with your cat. If this is the case, switch it back!
- **Medical condition** - If the vomiting keeps happening, this could be down to a medical condition, either disease or otherwise. You should really take him to the vet if vomiting is happening regularly/more than once or twice.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique It sounds like he could have been overactive on a full stomach, nothing to worry about. If it happens again though, a trip to the vets is probably best just to make sure all is well

Comment: @AbdullahShafique - You might want to avoid changing his food all the time, cats don't really like change, they like it consistent.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique Do your cat cough prior to the vomit? Is there any fur balls found in the vomit? If yes, the cat might had consumed too much of his fur which could not be digest and your cat's digestive system is not able to remove they properly. You can consider giving him some Hairballs Remedy or Cat grass to help him to remove the excess hairballs through his feces