# Can a 4yo cat be taught not to binge eat?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, feeding, eating

This is a 4 something year old Siamese cat. It is used to being fed precise meals.

I would love to train it to eat only as much as it needs. Currently, it eats everything in the bow, possibly vomiting. Is it possible at this age?

> [Why does my cat vomit almost every time I refill her food bowl?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/why-does-my-cat-vomit-almost-every-time-i-refill-her-food-bowl)

Comment: People usually can't train their cats to do much of anything, let alone something as against its instincts as eating less than it wants to. The accepted answer to the question you linked is the standard approach to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: **No.**

In general, there are 2 types of cats and dogs: Those who eat everything available and those who eat only as much as they need. From an evolutionary point of view eating everything edible is an advantage because it increases your chances of surviving times when no food at all is available to you.

As far as I know, what type of eater your pet is is solely dictated by their personality. There are cases when a moderate eater changed to eating as much as is available after not having enough food available to them. I have never ever heard of a case where an eat-everything pet reverted to only eating as much as they need.

---

There are automated feeders for cats that let a small amount of food fall into a bowl several times a day. There are also cats who are afraid of these feeders and don't accept them.

In general, overeating is bad for cats, not only because they become overweight, but also because they cannot process big amounts of food at once.

Cats cannot regulate the amount of digestive enzymes in their gut. Since they evolved to eat 8 - 12 small rodents or birds a day, their gut enzymes are regulated for those small portions. If a cat gobbles down an entire bowl of food at once, there aren't enough enzymes to digest all of it. The rest of the undigested food is then processed by bacteria in the large intestine, which causes bloating and the associated discomfort. You can read more it in [this scientific study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5753635/) or read a summary in [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/28806/12501).